# How to move viewcontroller to rootViewController on tabbar item click

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am working with `UITabbarController` and `UINavigationController` for my application. And i have created application with `UITabbar` base application it that i am giving different type of navigation controller to navigate view. As given below image.
[image]

But i have 1 problem which i describe as follows:

Suppose i have 5 `ViewController` and 3 `NavigationViewController` for that all five view controllers like View1 as `rootViewController` and view2 as subview. view 3 as `RootViewController` for 2nd `NavigationViewController` and view 4 as `subview` of 3rd `RootViewController` and others.

When i run application at that time view1 loaded as `RootViewController` now i am navigation to view 2 as it's  subView of view 1 at that time my tab bar selected to first tab. When i click on 2nd tab bar button it shows me view 3 as `RootViewController` for 2nd `NavigationController`.

And now i am clicking back to 1st `Tabbar` button to view view 1 but it shows me subview view 2. If i need to move to `RootViewController` i need to press back button to View my `RootView`.

So according to my sinario is it possible to set RootView for that particular tab bar so user can easily go to RootView without viewing subviews for all tab bar click items.

Please help me.

Comment: You mean when you click your tab bar button it should show your root view controller of your navigation controller?

Comment: Yes @jai you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code. When ever you are clicking the tab you be shown the root view of the navigationcontroller of the tab

```
 -(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{  
write your code here to move the ViewController as written below.(as your requirement)

[navcontrol1 popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[navcontrol2 popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[navcontrol3 popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the three view controllers(You five as your requirement), and then give each view control to the each separate navigationcontrollers. and then assign three navigationcontrollers to the tabbar as follows-

```
RideViewController* rideObj = [[RideViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RideViewController" bundle:nil];
RequestARideViewController* requestARideObj = [[RequestARideViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RequestARideViewController" bundle:nil];
MyAccountViewController* myAccntObj = [[MyAccountViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyAccountViewController" bundle:nil];


navCtrlObj1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rideObj];
navCtrlObj2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:requestARideObj];
navCtrlObj3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myAccntObj]

self._tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
self._tabBarController.delegate=self;
self._tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navCtrlObj1,navCtrlObj2,navCtrlObj3,nil];

-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{  
    write your code here to move the ViewController as written below.(as your requirement)


            [navCtrlObj1 popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            [navCtrlObj2 popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            [navCtrlObj3 popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the three view controllers, and then give each view control to the each separate navigationcontrollers. and then assign three navigationcontrollers to the tabbar.

```
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [self.tabBarController setDelegate:self];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navigationController1, navigationController2,navigationController3];

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
        write your code here to move the view 
    }
```